# Error 500 internal server error ajax request, jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a an ajax request that works Ok in xampp locally, but once it is on the server I'm getting the error 500 response, (internal server error), the request is this

```
    $("#numero").on("input", function(){
     var numero = $(this).val();
     if (numero != "" && isInt( numero ) && (numero >= 0 || numero <= 10000) ) {

        if (typeof holdAjax != "undefined") {
            clearTimeout(holdAjax);
        };
        holdAjax = setTimeout(function(){getInfo(numero);}, 500);
     } 
});
function getInfo(numero){
    $.post("get/boleta_informacion.php", { numero:numero }, function(data){
        var tds = $("tbody td");
        if (data) {
            $( tds[0] ).text(data[0]);
            $( tds[1] ).text(data[1][0]);
            $( tds[2] ).text(data[1][1]);
            $( tds[3] ).text(data[2]);
        } else {
            tds.text("");
            $( tds[3] ).text("Boleta no encontrada");
        }
    }, 'json' );
}
function isInt(n) {
   return n % 1 === 0;
}

$("#fecha").datepicker();
$( "#next" ).button();
$("#fcolilla").on("submit", function(e){
    var submit = false;
    var numero = $("#numero").val();
    var fecha =  $("#fecha").val();
    if (numero === "") {
        $( "<div title='Mensaje'>" ).html("<h3 style=''>Ingresa un numero de la boleta</h3>").dialog();
    } else if ( !isInt( numero ) ) {
        $( "<div title='Mensaje'>" ).html("<h3 style=''>Ingresa un numero entero</h3>").dialog();
    } else if (numero < 0 || numero > 10000) {
        $( "<div title='Mensaje'>" ).html("<h3 style=''>El numero debe estar en el rango  0-10000</h3>").dialog();
    } else if( fecha == "" ){
        $( "<div title='Mensaje'>" ).html("<h3 style=''>Ingresa la fecha en que la boleta fue vendida</h3>").dialog();
    } else {
            var request = $.ajax({
              url: "get/boleta_informacion.php",
              type: "POST",
              data: { numero : numero },
              dataType: "json",
              async: false
            });
            request.done(function( msg ) {
                if (msg) {

                    if ( msg[2] === "en venta" ) {
                        var boletaID = msg[0];
                        var colilla = {boletaID:boletaID,fecha:fecha};
                        $("#boletaID").val(boletaID);
                        var numeros = "";
                        for (var i = 0; i < msg[1].length; i++) {
                            numeros += msg[1][i];
                            if ( i < (msg[1].length-1)) {
                                numeros += ",";
                            };
                        };
                        $("#numeros").val( numeros );
                        submit = true;
                    } else {
                        $( "<div title='Mensaje'>" ).html("<h3 style=''>No se puede ingresar la colilla, el estado de la bolet es " + msg[2] +  "</h3>").dialog();
                    }
                } else {
                        $( "<div title='Mensaje'>" ).html("<h3 style=''>No encontrada</h3>").dialog();

                }
            });
            request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus,  errorThrown ) {
              alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus + " ", +  errorThrown);
            });
    }



    if (!submit) {
        e.preventDefault();
    };


});
```

I had a similar problem before, but with error code 305 I think, but can't remember very well, that time I solutioanted it by changind "ModSecurity status" in cpanel to "no active" or "Detect Mode", this time it is not taking any effect, is there something wrong with the code? 
And the server side is

```
<?php
include_once 'init.php';
if ( input::exists("get") || input::exists("post")) {
    if (!empty(Input::get("numero"))) {
        $numero = Input::get("numero");
        $b = new Boletas();
        $check = $b->checkNumero($numero);
        if ($check) {
            $boletaID = $check->boletaID;
            $numeros = $b->getNumeros( $boletaID );
            $estado = $b->getBoletaEstado($boletaID);
            echo json_encode([ $boletaID, $numeros, $estado ]);
        } else {
            echo json_encode(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Whats is going wrong with it?

Comment: Probably a php error, you can show errors with the following code: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Good trick, thanks a lot, the problem was the php script, the Input class was missespeled input, the lowercase i, instead of I, in localhost it makes no difference, in the server side it makes, should I erase the silly question?, although your comment contains very nice and useful info.

Comment: I may be mistaken and this might not be the cause of the 500 error, but aren't you doing a post with your ajax, while this line `if (!empty(Input::get("numero"))) {` seems to want a get request. If that's right you'll always return `json_encode(false)` Is that what you intend?

Comment: Glad that I could help! Please up vote the comment to help me ;) Thanks!

Comment: @vch  the method get of the class Input return post if !isset($_GET['xxx']), I was using $.get, but change it to post in an attempt to make it works.